# Rails renders HTML when JSON is requested when there is an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails as a JSON-only API server but whenever there is an exception in the a controller, say attempting to delete a record with an ID of 1 when it doesn't exist, Rails doesn't respond with JSON it responds with HTML, either a trace if in development or a generic 'something went wrong' page in production.

Right now I'm wrapping everything in a rescue and spitting out a JSON response manually...

```
class AmazonAccountsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json, :xml

  def destroy
    # Handle bad API calls.
    begin
      @account = AmazonAccount.find(params[:id])
      @account.destroy
      # unrelated code...
    rescue
      render :json => {:errors => {:bad => "ID doesn't exist."}}.to_json
    end
  end

end
```

but this doesn't seem like the ideal way to handle this.

This is in Rails 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`rescue_from`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rescue_from):

> If you want to do something a bit more elaborate when catching errors, you can use `rescue_from`, which handles exceptions of a certain type (or multiple types) in an entire controller and its subclasses.
>
> When an exception occurs which is caught by a `rescue_from` directive, the exception object is passed to the handler. The handler can be a method or a `Proc` object passed to the `:with` option. You can also use a block directly instead of an explicit `Proc` object.

So you could do something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    rescue_from your_list_of_exceptions..., :with => :some_exception_handler
private
    def some_exception_handler
        render :json => { :error => 'some error message of some sort' }, :status => :unprocessable_entity # or whatever status makes sense.
    end
end
```

The [API documentation on `rescue_from`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from) is worth a look as well.