# Rails renders html not json when exception raised

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, exception

I hope someone can assist with this problem.

I've got a web services app I'm writing in rails.  I'm using [RocketPants](https://github.com/filtersquad/rocket_pants) for the services and [Authority](https://github.com/nathanl/authority) for the authorization.

I've run into an issue with exception handling where the Authority "that's now allowed" exception (Authority::SecurityViolation) is rendering as HTML, rather than JSON.

I've documented the story in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jasonelston/4721540) and [this issue](https://github.com/nathanl/authority/issues/20).

I can replicate by raising an exception within my ApiController like `raise "blah"`, and I get a html error page.  I've tried using `rescue_from` like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489416/rails-renders-html-when-json-is-requested-when-there-is-an-error) with the same unsuccessful result.

I don't know where to from here. Anyone know of anything in the Rails exception handling stack that causes this? I'd be grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried this in your ApiController class ?

```
rescue_from StandardError, with: :render_unknown_error


def render_unknown_error(error)
  render(json: error.inspect, status: 500)
end
```

Comment: [Why You Should Never Rescue Exception in Ruby](http://daniel.fone.net.nz/blog/2013/05/28/why-you-should-never-rescue-exception-in-ruby/)
This article suggests you should catch StandardError or something even more specific.